# How to load a vectorDrawable from a xml file in sd card

Tags: android, vector, android-sdcard

we can load a vectordrawable form mipmap, drawable, assets. now I download a vector.xml form net and it is stored in SD card. how can I load it to a vectorDrawable?

we ususlly use 
`VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), R.drawable.my_vector, null)` to load a vector , But the file must be form Resources.

Comment: Why you want to do that?

Comment: the amount of data for a vertor.xml is smaller , so  it can be faster in transfer.

Comment: it is dynamica, it can be download form server. you can only store it in SD card

Comment: But , why are you downloading it from Internet?

Comment: the amount of data for a vertor.xml is smaller , so it can be faster in transfer.